# How to include a varying graphic in margins

Tags: graphics

I need to typeset a case report consisting mainly of text, with the occasional picture. This can be done in the `article` or `amsart` classes, of course, but I would like to include a varying graphic (a small gimmick) in the margins, much like in the [LEGO Progress Report](http://cache.lego.com/upload/contentTemplating/AboutUsCorporateResponsibilityContent/otherfiles/downloadEF7733FE56DFDFBC57D0DED578F73612.pdf) (the minifigures on pages 10, 16 and 17 for example).

My question, therefore, is how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use package [graphicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics) to include external graphic files into your document. To place it absolute at the current page, you may use package [textpos](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) or [eso-pic](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). If it should be placed as side note (aka margin note) you may either use `\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\marginwidth]{filename}}`. If this results in problems with the vertical position you should habe a look at package [marginfix](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginfix). If you simply don't wont the margin note to float at the margin, try package [marginnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) and `\marginnote{\includegraphics[wdith=\marginwidth]{filename}}`.

Here a simply `\marginpar` example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.eps}
%!
%%BoundingBox:100 100 172 172
100 100 moveto
72 72 rlineto
72 neg 0 rlineto
72 72 neg rlineto
stroke
100 100 moveto
/Times-Roman findfont
72 scalefont
setfont
(A) show
showpage
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[mpinclude]{scrartcl}
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{\marginparwidth}}
\recalctypearea
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\blindtext[3]

And now the
picture\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{\jobname.eps}}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: first page of the result of the example code]