# Section or chapter in header

Tags: header-footer

I am writing a document and I have made it, so that on every even page, the header shows the current chapter, and on every odd page it shows the current section. But how can I show either the current chapter or the current section in the header, depending on the fact that the current page already belongs to a section or not?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{scrreprt}                            
\usepackage{geometry}                           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}              
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles                          
\rohead{\chaptername :\ \rightmark}     
\lehead{\chaptername :\ \leftmark}      
\automark[section]{chapter}                                         
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
    \blindtext
    \chapter{2}
    \section{2.1}
    \blindtext
    \chapter{3}
    \blindtext
    \section{3.1}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the additive star version `\automark*`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{scrreprt}                            
\usepackage{geometry}                           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}              
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}% Add odd side marks without removing previous marks
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter:\enskip}% Put "chapter" oder "appendix" in front of the chapter number in running head
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}                         
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Erstes Kapitel}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\chapter{Zweites Kapitel}
\section{Erster Abschnitt des zweiten Kapitels}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\chapter{Drittes Kapitel}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\section{Erster Abschnitt des dritten Kapitels}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

The first `\automark[chapter]{chapter}` activates automatic running heads and defines a `\chaptermark` to set left and right mark and resets `\sectionmark` etc. The second `\automark*[section]{}` does only define `\sectionmark` to set the right mark (odd syntax: left argument → right mark; right argument → left mark). So you have chapter on the left and right pages until you have a `\section` that changes the running head of right pages to be the section.

Comment: Sorry, I'm away and so couldn't react to your comment directly. You are naturally right that the starred version of \automark make is easier to reset only \sectionmark.

Answer (score 1):

You should redefine \sectionmark so that it also sets the left mark. In KOMA-syntax e.g. like this (a simple `\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}` should work too, but looses some of the KOMA internals):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{Kapitel~}
\rohead{\leftmark}
\lehead{\leftmark}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}

\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Erstes Kapitel}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\chapter{Zweites Kapitel}
\section{Erster Abschnitt des zweiten Kapitels}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\chapter{Drittes Kapitel}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\section{Erster Abschnitt des dritten Kapitels}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `\rightmark` expands to something printable (using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/110998)).

```
\rohead{\setbox0=\hbox{\rightmark\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt\chaptername\ \leftmark\else Abschnitt \rightmark\fi}
\lehead{\chaptername\ \leftmark}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{scrreprt}                            
\usepackage{geometry}                           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}              
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles                          
\rohead{\setbox0=\hbox{\rightmark\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt\chaptername\ \leftmark\else Abschnitt \rightmark\fi}
\lehead{\chaptername\ \leftmark}      
\automark[section]{chapter}                                         
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Erstes Kapitel}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\chapter{Zweites Kapitel}
\section{Erster Abschnitt des zweiten Kapitels}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\chapter{Drittes Kapitel}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\section{Erster Abschnitt des dritten Kapitels}
    \Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not reliable -- the section number can change on the previous page. See e.g. `\chapter{Erstes Kapitel}
 blub \newpage blub \newpage blub \par
 \vspace{0.8\textheight}\par 
 blub \\blub
\section{Erster Abschnitt des ersten Kapitels}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Right, thanks; I have modified (corrected?) my answer.